# uniqueness theorem for ODE system

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a given continuous mapping. Suppose there is a constant $K$ such that

$||f(t,x)-f(t,y)|| \le K||x-y||$

for all $t \in \mathbb R, x, y, \in \mathbb R^n$. Then there is a unique continuously differentiable map $x:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ such that

$x(0)=x_0$, ${dx\over dt} =f(t,x(t)), (t,x)\in\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^n $

I proved when n=1. but I can't when $n \ge 2$

Comment: How did you prove it for the case of $n=1$?  Are you looking for global existence of $x$ or local existence in some neighborhood of $x_{0}$?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the proof of the [Picard-Lindelöf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) Theorem may be of help to you?